# Less disk space than provided by dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, storage

Sorry for the vague title, couldn't think of anything better.

I've bought a laptop about a month ago with Windows 10 pre-installed on it. Then I had decided to install elementaryOS alongside it. Since I didn't want to do it all on my own I followed the instructions here:

https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-elementary-os-luna/

Within these instructions is a part where you're supposed to create three partitions: root, home and swap. Now, keep in mind that I've done this over a month ago and only now noticed the problem. The biggest partition of them is the home partition (as mentioned in the article) so out of the total of 100GB I gave around 70GB to the home partition.

Today I was wondering how much disk space I have left on my linux partition and when I entered `gparted` this is what I saw:
[image]

When I check with `df -h` I get this:

[image]

Now, about the gparted: The 931GB drive that it shows is an HDD that I use as a secondary (data) storage - has nothing to do with either elementary or Windows 10.

The `df`, on the other hand does show the 69GB partition. So then I thought maybe nothing was wrong. But when I go to Files and hover over 'File System' (I couldn't take a screenshot of that, it disappears when I hit prntscr) it says '9.6GB/19.5 available'.

So where did the other 70GB go?

Additionally, in Windows 10 I can see a 77GB partition, for which at this point I am not sure whether it's the one I'm looking for or what:
[image]

As I said, I did the installation a while ago and, even though I'm pretty sure I had followed the instructions correctly, who knows. Maybe I missed something.

Anyway, is there a way to fix this problem (give the 70GB partition to elementaryOS) or will I just have to reinstall? If reinstallation is the only solution, what is the best way to do it without screwing up the Windows partition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press there and change it to `/dev/sdb`

[image: gparted]

---

About the other statement you hovering in [pantheon-files](/questions/tagged/pantheon-files) and seeing less space. You have mixed concepts, remember that in Linux you have mount points acting logically as one but they are separated. What you saw as "File System" is the same amount you see in the root mount point (`/`). You expected to see it all together but doesn't work that way